# Does the floodplain level for a creek change after an obstacle?

Tags: flooding

We have a nice creek going through our lot and a renovated barn on the other side. We have a creek crossing that was designed by an engineer. While it didn't have to be permitted (since it wasn't on the road to the actual dwelling), it meets the requirements for that, so the road surface is 1" above the 100 year floodplain and the culverts are designed to allow the full flow of water needed during a 100 year rainfall event.

[image: Creek crossing 6'1" tall with three 30" culverts]
Some general numbers: The crossing surface is 6'1" above the creek level and there are three 30" culverts that pass through. This is what was required by the original design from the engineer. (The picture of the crossing is from the downstream side, if it matters.)

At this spot where the crossing is, the banks are high and the "overflow" area is narrower than farther down where I want to put a footbridge. Since we moved in here, in 2017, we have seen three 100 year rainfall events (two of those were in one day, one pre-dawn and one in the evening) and a 700 year rainfall event. During and after the rainfall, I go down and check on this and several other areas to see how they're holding up, then I go and check after the rainfall as well. Whenever I have looked at the crossing during these massive rainfall events, the water is always going over the top of the crossing and the water level on the downstream side of the crossing is significantly lower than on the upstream side. It's always like this:[image: Diagram 1 - water lower on downstream side]

When the flooding does not go above the top of the inside of the culverts, there still seems to be a higher water level on the upstream side, but it's difficult to tell for sure.

Is the lower water level on the downstream side normal under the circumstances, or is it happening because debris is clogging the culverts nor not going through it easily and creating a backup that forces the water to rise up and go over the top of the crossing? In other words, during a flood that's just over a 100 year rainfall event, is it more normal for the water level to be the same on the upstream and downstream sides, like this:
[image]

Which is normal for these higher level rainfall events? Is the crossing enough of an obstruction that it raises the water level on the upstream side even though we're using the specified sized culverts? Or should the water level be the same on the downstream side as well as the upstream side?

It makes a difference in what I can do with building a footbridge downstream. If the water level should be the same, I have to build a sturdier footbridge. If it's normal for it to be lower after something like the crossing, I can go with a smaller footbridge and I have ideas I can use to make it survive flooding more easily.

---

Addendum: After seeing responses, I think I need to add that when I'm talking about putting in a footbridge, I don't mean a structure nearly as expensive as this. I'm thinking of just a wooden bridge that rests on footings on each side.

Comment: The culverts create a choke point so once you get close to full flow there will be a drop in the depth of water, would I build a foot bridge down stream with less no I would use the same size or larger culvert or build a bridge above the level not lower, why? If something really gets stuck and the flow over the roadway washes out (this can happen where the roadway is not concrete & rock reenforced then the foot bridge would be at risk of being destroyed it happens to roadways in the mountains built for traffic so I would not want to loose both with a bad event.

Comment: Hydrodynamics can be complicated. You indicate the downstream side is always lower, and I think that's a good indication of how water behaves in your spot. I do have to slightly differ in prognostication with @EdBeal here; if the roadway washes out the water level will drop a lot compared to seconds before washout. Whether the level will still be too high for the footbridge depends on how far downstream it's from the failed roadway. It seems there's a lot of formulas to which we don't have inputs, but the level tends to drop off quite quickly once an obstruction collapses. Consult an engineer.

Comment: Since it's backing up in things OTHER than the single "700 year event" it's clearly not actually properly designed for "100 year" events.

Comment: @EdBeal I've added a note about the foot bridge: Simple wooden bridge with footings on each end. Not something with culverts or concrete. But if the flooding were severe enough that it wiped out this crossing, what it does to a small footbridge is going to be a negligible problem in comparison.

Comment: @dandavis As I mentioned to Ed Beal, if this crossing washes out, then losing a small footbridge downstream is a tiny concern compared to replacing the roadway!

Comment: @Ecnerwal Actually, I should have clarified that the other events were at least 100 year events - except for one. That one I'm not sure about and by the time I found a resource where I could check on that information, I had forgotten the date of that event. However, that early event (before experience taught me to track these things) may have led to the water topping the crossing because of heavy debris in the culverts. It looked like there might be something there during the flooding, but later, when I could investigate more, I couldn't tell if something had been there or not.

Comment: @SteveSh I remember (now that you mention it) discussing that issue with the engineer - not only for this, but for the main driveway. So that may answer my question. (Those discussions were back in '15 and '16, if I remember - so there's been a LOT of time since I had to think about that.) Thank you for bringing that up - I had COMPLETELY forgotten those discussions. I remember going over that issue with the county environmental people when discussing our original driveway construction and handling an ephemeral stream. If you want to write that up as an answer, I'll select it.

Comment: Tango , ok on the foot bridge but the washout issue is real I believe Harper covered  it well+. Design a spillway in the road that would wash out and not loose the culverts and the nice crossing , I currently have a tree that went down last week blocking some water on our creek if that breaks loose it will jam down stream at a larger log jam, but if it were coming down to your culvert it could effectively block one or more culverts and create the washout problem with normal high flow times, I would put footings at the old high flow marks in the bank this is how I set an irrigation pump deck.

Comment: @EdBeal I mentioned, as a comment for Harper, that one of the head-cutting areas (around the culverts) is not a problem, since there is no opening for water to get in. The concern would be right by the top. I talked with an engineer about this today (someone with the county) and the issue on the downstream side is mitigated with the rocks I already have there as a (I forget the exact term, but I may be right) flow attenuator. (cont'd)

Comment: @EdBeal (Cont'd) The problem is finding high flow marks. I have neighbors who have lived in this area for decades. I know our barn was not flooded in the past during heavy events like hurricanes Isabel, Irene, Camille, and Agnes. So that's one point that's above the high water markers. But as to the actual high water mark, nobody's sure. I know the highest **I** have seen it, but I was trying to establish something more reliable.

Answer (score 5):

We can't possibly answer your direct question. It totally depends on terrain downstream, which

What you have is a dam.  Specifically a "dry dam". An earth-filled dam with a stone or concrete skin.  The two stone walls were never imagined to resist side-force from the impounded water, and would fall right over without the earth.

The problem is, you are going to lose the earth, due to **head-cutting** from the flow of water.  See bright blue arrows.

[image]

*That is a dam.*

In 2017, the Oroville dam was famously backed into a corner when their river valve outlet was down for repairs, and the main spillway broke, taking out the generator power lines. They were down to the broken spillway and the never-tested emergency spillway, and they [learned all about head-cutting](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jxNM4DGBRMU).

Anyway, you have risk of head-cutting in all the places I marked - churn over the first wall digging up the gravel that supports the first wall, churn after the second wall undermining its foundation, and leakage between wall and culverts eroding and causing liquefaction in the fill material.  This would result in catastrophic failure of the dam, releasing all the impounded water in a tidal wave.

The cure for this is a proper "emergency spillway" so that overtopping occurs in a location of your choosing, over surfaces built to endure it.  Not like Oroville lol.  That would be a lowering of your road at a particular point, so that overflow water will divert through that low spot and never over-top the dam.

Anyway, as far as your foot bridge, the same issues will arise with over-topping, unless you provide considerably more passage under it.

Comment: Thank you for the warning about head cutting. I don't see how the water will get in around the upstream openings of the culverts, since the concrete there doesn't leave any opening for water to get in. (Also, after construction, when the stone work was added, the mason added a layer there to seal any openings there.) The top spot is one I can watch easily. It's the bottom point on the downstream side I have to watch. I would think that spot would only be in trouble if there were a heavy flood that lasted for a long time.

Comment: Also, for a footbridge, I was basically thinking of something not nearly as complex or big - just a wooden span over the creek.

Answer (score -1):

IMHO, the engineer screwed up! The 100 year flood plain (where the water from the creek will go during a once in a hundred year flood) is determined prior to the damming caused by the culvert - that is, where the water will spread out if the crossing/culvert was not there. If my property were upstream of that culvert and started suffering flooding due to the natural water flow being impeded by the crossing, there would be a major lawsuit to deal with.

**Note on the Footbridge**

A simple footbridge, supported by footings on each bank is not going to impede water flow (until the water reaches the level of the footbridge).  So I would not think something like this would impact the 100 year flood plain determination.

**A Case Study**

For an interesting case look up "Ellicott City Floods".  Ellicott City is an old mill town in Maryland that experienced 2 1,000 year floods in 2 or 3 years, 2016 & 2018 I think.  One of the reasons given for the extensive flooding that occurred is because the major streams that flow through the town have had buildings erected in their natural flood plains.  According to one of the engineering reports I read, these buildings prevent the waters from flowing out onto the flood plain and act as a dam (just like your roadway culvert) and causes water to back up hill into the town.

Here's [some of the video](https://apps.npr.org/ellicott-city/?fbclid=IwAR2IRXvAA3GKLyhfFgfxo4bH_MK61GmOKxWN8pvMcH0w-l137ByZSYIJULY) from those floods.

Comment: When you duplicate a comment as an answer, please delete the comment.

Comment: I've addressed a few of the points you make here above, in response to your comment, so, with that in mind, that first paragraph in this answer is a non sequitur.